# Function throws error [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am working in an Angular4 application in this I need to consume the API response .For that I have put the below function and it throws the error as in my title.

I have referred some Stackoverflow posts but nothing is worked for me .

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.CartdataService.get_Product_Categories().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dropdownData = data.json();
      });
}
```

Here in this line I got the mentioned error

```
this.dropdownData = data.json();
```

These are my Headers

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CartdataService } from '../../services/cartdata.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: What's `get_Product_Categories()` ?

Comment: @bugs function which is referred from service file

Comment: What if you do not use the .json() in the subscribe method, but in the response in the service class? Like: `return this.http.get(URLJSON)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.onError);`. Afterwards, you can also do: `this.service.method().subscribe(res => this.data = res);`

Comment: @BrianM the new HTTP client automatically converts plain text responses to JSON.

Comment: @BrianM returns the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

In the new HttpClient, you don't have to parse your result to JSON.

Simply remove the line, and it should work.

Comment: should I remove the header.?

Comment: That's not an header, that's an import. And no, remove `this.dropdownData = data.json()`

Comment: By using dropdownData I am iterating the values inside the dropdown ,If I removed it then there is no data in dropdown .

Comment: Seriously, make an effort. `this.dropdownData = data`.

Comment: please refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-ijkwbc?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah well maybe **if you use the same modules you are using in your question**, this would work. **[Here is a proper blitz, with the correct modules and dependencies](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-q3yvvz?file=app/app.module.ts)**.

Comment: Are you serious ? I gave you a working blitz just before !

Comment: yep,For me everything is working fine in stackblitz if I applied the same code then it will show a magic in my real proj

Comment: Here I have reproduced my code ,Please help me to fix it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksntvy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Please see the html file there is something missing

Comment: In the html file (dropdownData ) shows this Identifier 'dropdownData' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Comment: did you checked it ,Waiting for your guidance

Comment: No I didn't check it and I won't. I gave you the answer to your issue, I'm not your personal code monkey. If you need help, you make another question. If you don't want to do that, then you rely on my workign stackblitz. It's not hard to copy-paste code.

Comment: man I just copied your code and paste it but it shows only one data .and If I clicked on it is not get clicked .

Comment: I took 3 seconds to look at it : the `index.html` files are different. So no, you didn't copy and pasted.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to look in the index.html files

Comment: can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100381/while-looping-api-response-in-accordion-menu-data-missing-in-angular4